# Xcode - The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached (Bug?)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

It is the first time I posted in Stack overflow (excuse my bad English).
I'm starting to learn Swift with Xcode and trying to use a new app with a personnal free account.
When I try to launch the App in my Iphone, Xcode displays "Unable to install" because "The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached." but as shown in the screenshot, the installed apps windows ([Screenshot of Devices and simulator Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR0Wq.jpg)) does not show any app.

I had already enable Legacy Build System in the project settings and the Signing profile and certificates seemed ok.

Do you have any idea ?... Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide !...

Unable to install "Compteur"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain

### Code: -402620383

The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620383

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue you can see in the latest Xcode 11.4 Release notes.
I suggest you to try what Apple advises as a workaround until they fix it.

"When targeting devices running iOS 13.3.1, tvOS 13.3.1, watchOS 6.1, or later using a free Apple Developer account, app extensions incorrectly count against the limit of three apps installed simultaneously. When this happens, Xcode reports an error: “The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached.” (59264389) (FB7568073)

Workaround: Delete apps signed with your free account from your device and also remove any associated provisioning profiles from the device using Xcode’s Devices window. If your app contains more than two app extensions, remove them to remain under the three app limit."

Link here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_4_release_notes

Comment: Thank you so much for your help CoachThys. After, I right click to the connected device to show provisionning profile which contains the others profiles (this feature is quite hidden!.....). Thank you again for taking time to answer my question.

Comment: thanks CoachThys, however it did not work for me, although tried it several times! . Removed all apps, removed all associated profiles several times, still the same error