# XCode Error: The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Get this error when trying to install the app on a device to test. I have no apps that I'v developed on the device, so the error does not make sense.

Have tried the solutions mentioned in other similar Stackoverflow posts:

- unpair and pair the device again
- delete profiles from Window >
  Devices (I had only one profile)

XCode version: 11.5

Phone iOS version: 13.5

Error Details:

```
The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620383
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487925;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008021)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011bc5081a DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 233
1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011bc91f70 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
2   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001029e9145 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 73
3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011bc91ca8 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1654
4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000011bb08e91 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.352 + 4165
5   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102b1c7e4 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
6   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000102b1e426 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1194
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff726606c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff72661658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff72666c44 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff726675d6 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff72670c09 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff728bba3d _pthread_wqthread + 290
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff728bab77 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
```

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60899957/1187415 ?

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61978102/13604319 That's what worked for me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

in Xcode go to Window → Devices then under Installed Apps delete some of your apps and afterwards I could run my own apps on the device again.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it is enough to simply delete the Apps from your iPhone.

However, sometimes Xcode doesn't seem to recognise this fast enough.

> In this case inside Xcode go to Window --> Devices --> Installed Apps and delete some of them.

NOTE: Development Teams that aren't enrolled in the Apple Developer Programm are limited to only three Apps at a time on a physical device.

Answer (score 0):

**What did not work:**

> deleting the provisioning profiles that are installed on the device (from the device manager in Xcode)
>
> cleared out any apps that I had installed on the device
>
> cleared out sufficient space from the phone

**What did work:**

In my case I think the problem arose because I recently joined the developer programme.

So it was like 3 days ago everything was working fine. But after I made payments and my membership was under review, I started getting this error. Even after approval of membership I was getting the same error.

So I just thought that I would revoke my older dev certificate and create a new one with the "new" account.

And that worked.
So, I suspect in my scenario the privilege changes was the issue.